# how to cross out a certain text displayed on the screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game, there are certain objects that are tagged with "TargetObj", these objects have their names displayed on the screen like this:

```
GameObject[] targetObjects;
List<GameObject> targetObjectsList; 
private TextMeshProUGUI mytext;
public TMP_FontAsset FontAssetA;
[SerializeField] GameObject TargetsCanvas;
void Start()
    {
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
        targetObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TargetObj");

        targetObjectsList = new List<GameObject>();
        foreach (var obj in targetObjects)
        {
            mytext = CreateText(TargetsCanvas.transform);
            mytext.text = "• " + obj.name;
            mytext.font = FontAssetA;   
        }
    }
static TextMeshProUGUI CreateText(Transform parent)
    {
        var go = new GameObject();
        go.transform.parent = parent;
        var text = go.AddComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        text.fontSize = 20;
        return text;
    }
```

They look like this:

[image]

The `TargetsCanvas` inspector:

[image]

Once the player picks up all tagged objects, he wins:

```
     if (PickingUp)
            {
                if (currentlyPickedUpObject == null)
                {
                    if (lookObject != null)
                    {
                        PickupObject();
                        if (lookObject.CompareTag("TargetObj") && !targetObjectsList.Contains(lookObject.gameObject))
                        {
                            if (aSource)
                            {
                                aSource.Play();
                            }
                            targetObjectsList.Add(lookObject.gameObject);
                            if (targetObjectsList.Count == targetObjects.Length)
                            {
                                winUI.SetActive(true);
                                Time.timeScale = 0f;
                                //SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
                                //Time.timeScale = 1f;
                            }
    
                        }
                    }
 public void PickupObject()
        {

         physicsObject = lookObject.GetComponentInChildren<PhysicsObjects>();
         currentlyPickedUpObject = lookObject;
         pickupRB = currentlyPickedUpObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
         pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
         physicsObject.playerInteractions = this;
       pickupRB.transform.parent = PickupParent.transform;

        //StartCoroutine(physicsObject.PickUp()); 

    }
```

I'm trying to cross out the name object on the screen once this object is picked up. I know that I can use this line to cross out a text:

```
mytext.fontStyle = FontStyles.Strikethrough;
```

but in my case, I don't know where exactly to use it to achieve what I want. any idea?

Comment: Don’t the textmesh pro fonts allow you to make one with crossed out?

Answer (score 0):

When using TextMeshPro Text, you can add a rich text tags to strikethrough any part of your string.

For example:

1. Make sure Rich Text is enabled under Extra Settings in your TMP Text Component
   [image]
2. Use start tag <s> and end tag </s> to define where the strikethrough starts and ends[image]

An example of setting this in code would be something like

```C#
public string textToStrike; //"Coffee Cup"
const string STRIKE_START = "<s>";
const string STRIKE_END = "</s>";
outputText = STRIKE_START + textToStrike + STRIKE_END;
```

Result outputText = <s>Coffee Cup</s>

You could even make a method that returns the inputted value as striked out if you wanted.

For example

```C#
private string StrikeText(string input)
{
     string output = STRIKE_START + input + STRIKE_END;
     return output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it is really helpful. but can you check my question again? I edited it to make the issue clear.